# Azure DevOps Test API - How to create or get the value of actionPath

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

Clerify,
By **get** I mean to generate or get the number I need to provide, NOT the number already exists in the test results.

When creating tests result with steps information (manual run), need to provide value for a field called `actionPath`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/action%20results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#testactionresultmodel

Is there a way to find or generate this value so I can create tests results using the API? It seems there is no consistent or clear way of what or where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some try/error I have found the solution.

#### Phase One - Get the Step ID

> You need to install [HTML Agility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) nuget to be able to extract data from the HTML.

When creating a test step, it will have an automatic ID which is represented in it's HTML. In order to get the test steps HTML and extract the IDs, need to use the following code (or similar):

```
// create a client (assuming you know how to create vss connection)
var client = vssConnction.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

// get the work item with all fields
var item = client.GetWorkItemAsync(<item id>, expand: WorkItemExpand.All).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

// get the HTML
var html = $"{item.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps"]}"

// load the HTML into DOM object
var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

// extract all IDs. The actionPath is the hex form of the step ID (.ToString("x"))
var ids = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//step").Select(i => int.Parse(i.GetAttributeValue("id", "0")).ToString("x"));
```

#### Phase Two - Get the Action Path

The `actionPath` is the hex form of the step ID in 8 digitis with leading zeros (e.g. id `10` will be `0000000a`). In order to parse the id into action path use the following code (or similar):

```
var actionPath = ids.Select(i => new string('0', 8 - i.Length) + i);
```

Now you can tell the actionPath when creating an action test result

#### Full Code Workflow (was not validated for errors)

```
// credentials
var basicCredential = new VssBasicCredential("", personalAccessToken);
var credentials = new VssCredentials(basicCredential);

// connection
var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("your collection URI"), credentials);

// clients
var testManagement = connection.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();

// test points
var pointsFilter = new PointsFilter { TestcaseIds = new[] { <test_id>, <test_id>, ... } };
var pointsQuery = new TestPointsQuery() { PointsFilter = pointsFilter };
var points = testManagement.GetPointsByQueryAsync(query, project).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Points;

// test run
var runCreateModel = new RunCreateModel(name: "My Test Run", pointIds: points, plan: new ShallowReference(id: $"{<test_plan_id>}"));
var testRun = testManagement.CreateTestRunAsync(runCreateModel, "<project name>").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

// iteration
var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
var date = new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute, dateTime.Second, dateTime.Millisecond, dateTime.Kind);
var iteration = new TestIterationDetailsModel
{
    Id = 1,
    StartedDate = date,
    CompletedDate = date.AddMinutes(5),
    Comment = "My Test Iteration"
}

// action
var actionResult = new TestActionResultModel
{
    ActionPath = "<actionPath>",           // the one we extracted from the HTML
    StepIdentifier = "<the_test_step_id>", // the one we extracted from the HTML
    IterationId = <the_iteration_id>,
    StartedDate = date,
    Outcome = TestOutcome.Passed,
    CompletedDate = date.AddMinutes(5)
};

iteration.ActionResults = new List<TestActionResultModel> { actionResult };

// test result
var testCaseResult = testManagement
    .GetTestResultByIdAsync("<project name>", testRun.Id, <test_results_id>, ResultDetails.Iterations)
    .GetAwaiter()
    .GetResult()
    .First();
testCaseResult.IterationDetails.Add(iteration);
testManagement.UpdateTestResultsAsync(new[] { testCaseResult }, "<project name>", testRun.Id).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to create or get the value of actionPath

You can use the below [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#resultdetails) to get the value of `actionPath`.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}?detailsToInclude=iterations&api-version=6.0
```

Test in Postman:

[image]

Comment: This is the get - when the results are already exists, I need to create them using the API - not getting an existing results. That means I need to provide the actionPath

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear about the Get thing

Comment: It is possible - I do it every day, the problem was to match an actionPath to the test ID, Please look at the solution I have found - the step ID is decimal while the actionPath is hex-decimal, just need to convert and it works.